# (Flutter, Apple sign in) Apple sign in refuses to work

Tags: flutter, firebase, apple-sign-in

I have a flutter application that I'm working on, the application is already on the [google play store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cyke.gpt) but not on the apple store as yet.

I've been trying to get apple sign in to work so that apple users are able to easily sign in to the app and make payments easier, Ive integrated the required plugins and done the set ups as well according to [dbestech video] on youtube (setting up apple developer profile and sorting out the certificate, adding apple sign in to the runner as wellas setting up firebase and linking it up)

This is the coding I have for apple sign in:

```
Future<void> appleSignIn() async {
    _isLoading = true;
    update();
    try {
      final credential = await SignInWithApple.getAppleIDCredential(
        scopes: [
          AppleIDAuthorizationScopes.email,
          AppleIDAuthorizationScopes.fullName,
        ],
      );
      final OAuthProvider oAuthProvider = OAuthProvider('apple.com');
      final AuthCredential appleCredential = oAuthProvider.credential(
        idToken: credential.identityToken,
        accessToken: credential.authorizationCode,
      );
      await _auth.signInWithCredential(appleCredential);
      GetStorage().write('isLogged', true);
      checkLogin();
    } catch (e) {
      Get.defaultDialog(
        title: 'Error',
        middleText: 'Something went wrong.\nPlease try again later.',
        confirm: TextButton(
          onPressed: () => Get.back(),
          child: const Text('Ok'),
        ),
      );
    } finally {
      _isLoading = false;
      update();
    }
  }


checkLogin() {
    final User? user = _auth.currentUser;
    if (user == null) {
      Get.offAll(() => const LoginView());
    } else {
      if (subscriptionController.isSubscribed) {
        Get.offAll(() => const HomeScreen());
      } else {
        Get.to(() => const UpgradeToProPop());
      }
    }
  }
```

When i run the app to test it (on an ios device) the only error that shows is:

```
10.10.0 - [FirebaseCore][I-COR000005] No app has been configured yet.
10.10.0 - [FirebaseFirestore][I-FST000001] Listen for query at userMessageCount/.../userMessageCount failed: Missing or insufficient permissions.
```

I did some research on the above issue and changed the rules on my fireStore database to :

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

After doing these changes I'm still left with the same result,

The application allows the user to click on the "Sign in with apple" button, the apple sign in pop up shows and lets the user sign in, it shows that its loading and a tick appears making me think it's worked but as soon as the pop up is gone the catch is implemented in the "appleSignIn" code above, I've checked the firebase authentication tab to see if maybe the user info worked but the app just didn't register and its not there telling me that the issue is somewhere between getting the user info from apple and actually working with firebase.